# Windows Phone 7 JSON parsing error

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

I have this JSON string

```
{ "rs:data": { "z:row": [ {"Lead": "", "Industry": "Other Commercial", "ID": "908", "Name": "3PAR Ltd." }, {"Lead": "Ebeling, Kevin R.", "Industry": "Retail", "ID": "1", "Name": "7-Eleven" } ] }}
```

Now I am getting data in the above format from a web service into Win phone 7.
But while trying to parse I am facing a error:

```
    void fetcher_GetClientsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference2.GetClientsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        StringReader reader;
        reader = new StringReader(e.Result);
        IList<Clientclass> cc;
        string MyJsonString = reader.ReadToEnd(); //

        cc = Deserialize(MyJsonString); 
    }


    public static IList<Clientclass> Deserialize(string json)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IList<Clientclass>));
            return (IList<Clientclass>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
```

My data has to parsed as per clientclass, where clientclass is:

```
    public class Clientclass
    {
        string _id;
        string _name;
        string _industry;
        string _lead;

        public string ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
        public string Industry
        {
            get {return _industry; }
            set { _industry= value; }
        }
        public string Lead
        {
            get { return _lead; }
            set { _lead = value; }
        }
    }
```

Please note there are more than one records in JSON string.

Thanks
santu

Answer (score 1):

You are deserializing the wrong type (IList instead of List of ClientClass - the [original post had typeof(IList)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d82c0f8b-2f57-4d4f-87c0-dab9364f2af2/view-source) however Chris corrected this as part of his code formatting edits).  You should be doing:

```
public static List<Clientclass> Deserialize(string json)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Clientclass>));
        return (List<Clientclass>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

Also, your JSON includes stuff you are not decoding.  If you want to use the above method, your JSON would have to be:

```
[ {"Lead": "", "Industry": "Other Commercial", "ID": "908", "Name": "3PAR Ltd." }, {"Lead": "Ebeling, Kevin R.", "Industry": "Retail", "ID": "1", "Name": "7-Eleven" } ]
```

In order to decode the string from your original post, you'll need a containing class, and define [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attributes to handle the names:

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "rs:data")]
        public ClassB Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        [DataMember(Name="z:row")]
        public List<Clientclass> Row { get; set; }
    }
```

Then deserialize ClassA:

```
    public static ClassA Deserialize(string json)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ClassA));
            return (ClassA)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't this json be representive of a dictionary<string, List<ClientClass>> with one item, name = 'z:row' and a List<ClientClass>?